# Import JSON data into Node.js object

Tags: node.js, json

I am writing an Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe program in Node.js and am storing the board state in a Board object, with each of the local boards represented by a Square object.

```
// Constructor for the Board object
constructor() {
    this._A1 = new Square();
    this._A2 = new Square();
    this._A3 = new Square();

    this._B1 = new Square();
    this._B2 = new Square();
    this._B3 = new Square();

    this._C1 = new Square();
    this._C2 = new Square();
    this._C3 = new Square();

    this._winner = null;
    this._lastMove = null;
}
```

```
// Constructor for the Square object
constructor() {
    this._X1 = null;
    this._X2 = null;
    this._X3 = null;

    this._Y1 = null;
    this._Y2 = null;
    this._Y3 = null;

    this._Z1 = null;
    this._Z2 = null;
    this._Z3 = null;

    this._winner = null;
    this._winningCombination = null;
}
```

I wanted to be able to load an existing game, so I set my program to export the current Board object state.

```
fs.writeFileSync('output/save.json', JSON.stringify(board, null, '\t'), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

When I try to import the JSON save file back in, the operation completes successfully, but I get the error `this[square].checkWins is not a function` when playing the game. `square.checkWins()` is a function under the Square class, so it seems that the imported JSON is overriding the existing object (i.e. `this._A1 = new Square();`). How can I import a save state of the game while preserving both the Board and Square classes such that I can access the functions of both?

```
// Code used to import JSON save file
const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(importPath);
Object.assign(board, JSON.parse(jsonData));
console.log(board);
```

Edit: This is what my JSON save file looks like

```
{
    "_A1": {
        "_X1": "X",
        "_X2": "O",
        "_X3": "X",
        "_Y1": "O",
        "_Y2": "X",
        "_Y3": "X",
        "_Z1": "O",
        "_Z2": "X",
        "_Z3": "O",
        "_winner": "tie",
        "_winningCombination": null
    },
    "_A2": {
        "_X1": null,
        "_X2": "O",
        "_X3": "X",
        "_Y1": "X",
        "_Y2": "X",
        "_Y3": "X",
        "_Z1": "X",
        "_Z2": null,
        "_Z3": null,
        "_winner": "X",
        "_winningCombination": "Y1Y3VVS"
    },
    "_A3": {
        "_X1": "O",
        "_X2": "O",
        "_X3": "X",
        "_Y1": "X",
        "_Y2": "X",
        "_Y3": "O",
        "_Z1": "O",
        "_Z2": "X",
        "_Z3": "O",
        "_winner": "tie",
        "_winningCombination": null
    },
    "_B1": {
        "_X1": null,
        "_X2": null,
        "_X3": "X",
        "_Y1": "O",
        "_Y2": "O",
        "_Y3": "O",
        "_Z1": "X",
        "_Z2": null,
        "_Z3": "O",
        "_winner": "O",
        "_winningCombination": "Y1Y3VVS"
    },
    "_B2": {
        "_X1": "O",
        "_X2": null,
        "_X3": "O",
        "_Y1": null,
        "_Y2": "X",
        "_Y3": "O",
        "_Z1": "X",
        "_Z2": "X",
        "_Z3": "X",
        "_winner": "X",
        "_winningCombination": "Z1Z3VVS"
    },
    "_B3": {
        "_X1": "O",
        "_X2": null,
        "_X3": null,
        "_Y1": "O",
        "_Y2": "O",
        "_Y3": "X",
        "_Z1": "X",
        "_Z2": "X",
        "_Z3": "X",
        "_winner": "X",
        "_winningCombination": "Z1Z3VVS"
    },
    "_C1": {
        "_X1": null,
        "_X2": "O",
        "_X3": "O",
        "_Y1": "X",
        "_Y2": "X",
        "_Y3": "X",
        "_Z1": "O",
        "_Z2": null,
        "_Z3": null,
        "_winner": "X",
        "_winningCombination": "Y1Y3VVS"
    },
    "_C2": {
        "_X1": "O",
        "_X2": "O",
        "_X3": null,
        "_Y1": "O",
        "_Y2": "O",
        "_Y3": null,
        "_Z1": "O",
        "_Z2": null,
        "_Z3": "O",
        "_winner": "O",
        "_winningCombination": "X1Z1HHS"
    },
    "_C3": {
        "_X1": null,
        "_X2": "X",
        "_X3": "O",
        "_Y1": "X",
        "_Y2": "X",
        "_Y3": "O",
        "_Z1": null,
        "_Z2": "X",
        "_Z3": null,
        "_winner": "X",
        "_winningCombination": "X2Z2HHS"
    },
    "_winner": "tie",
    "_lastMove": null
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your json file looks like?

Comment: I just edited the post to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
importJSON(jsonData) {
    for (const [key] of Object.entries(this)) {
        if(typeof jsonData[key] === 'object' && jsonData[key] !== null) {
            Object.assign(this[key], jsonData[key]);
        }
        else {
            this[key] = jsonData[key];
        }
    }
}
```